# How to implement session management in spring authorization server

Tags: spring-security, spring-authorization-server

I have a federated spring authorisation server which uses social login. To restrict the number user login sessions, enabled the spring security session management but it didn’t worked out for me. I would like to implement following:

1. When user logout, terminate the user session and ask him to login through social login again.
2. If user already logged in, trying to login from another device or browser, we should terminate the old session (spring security session management had this)

Issue is even though I’m enabled the session management, it is still allowing multiple login sessions across devices/browsers.

Comment: It's not clear whether you're talking about session management on the client or the authorization server, or you're somehow trying to do this with a combination of both. Please share a [minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or at least some code demonstrating what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi @SteveRiesenberg The goal is to implement spring security concurrent session control at spring authorization server with strategy of oldest logged in session of the user should be expired (maxSessionsPreventsLogin()).

But issue is I'm able to login multiple times from different sources and able to use all logged in sessions :/
Tried on latest sample here  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/main/samples/demo-authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/config/DefaultSecurityConfig.java

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg please find the src code https://github.com/maradanasai/spring-authorization-server/tree/test_session_mngt in samples section. I have made edits to demo client & authorization server. username & password is user1, password.

Expectation is session mngt should expire old logged in session if it exceeds maxSessions() dsl value. I tried with different browsers, able to login multiple time and can fetch data from resource server.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg kindly help check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're finding is on the client application where you configure concurrent session control for `oauth2Login()`. Maximum sessions is enforced correctly on the authorization server, which only uses `formLogin()`.

First, your client sample is missing a `HttpSessionEventPublisher` bean, as suggested [in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/session-management.html#ns-concurrent-sessions).

Second, your client sample is not configured to use Spring Session for backing the session store. Because of this, it is using an in-memory `SessionRegistry` implementation, which is the default. This in-memory implementation is simple in nature, and maps the sessions by the `principal`. It therefore considers two users who log in with OAuth2 to be different, because it simply uses the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods of the principal (an instance of `DefaultOidcUser`). These methods do not consider the same user from different logins to be equal, because they have different values in the token response from the authorization server.

In order for this sample to work correctly with concurrent session controls, you will need to add and configure spring-session as the backing store for your sessions on the client application, which is quite easy to do. See a [list of samples and guides](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/samples.html) to get started.

It might also be worth [reporting this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/new/choose) as a bug in spring-security, since the in-memory (default) implementation of `SessionRegistry` is not compatible with `DefaultOidcUser` and `DefaultOAuth2User` as the principal. However, it shouldn't be an issue in production as you should not rely on in-memory implementations for production deployments. You would normally configure Spring Session for your application at a minimum.

Comment: Hi @Steve I've got to know this after lot of debugging through concurrent strategy and filter logic. I have tried the other option, using spring session as backing store (with redis in my case) but still I'm able to fetch the data from multiple logged in sessions even though I defined the maxSesssions dsl with 1 value. Kindly assist

Comment: Please be courteous and show your work. If you have made changes, please update the question and show your progress, update the code and configuration to show what you've done, and help others help you. If you're asking for help troubleshooting your setup, please show others you are willing to put in the time and effort to work together on a solution.

Comment: Sorry @Steve that was poor part on my side. I have found that is not working due to not updated the session registry bean with spring session backstore impl (in my case it's redis). Now it is working fine https://github.com/maradanasai/spring-authorization-server/tree/test_session_mngt What happens if add concurrent sessions control logic at both demo-client and demo-authorization server? why it is not suggested to impl. at auth server? 

Also if I would like to enable the session controls only for oauth2Login() but not for username/password auth, can you please suggest the changes?

Comment: In my actual usecase implementation, client is spring cloud gateway, where spring reactive didn't support session control like we have for servlet security (It's implemented in 3.3.0-M1 but it takes time to adopt into spring cloud release train).

I would like to get this session controls work for oauth2Login() where spring cloud gateway is oauth2 client for spring authorization server (with federated auth support). Kindly provide your inputs, thanks

Comment: You simply need to make sure you provide `HttpSessionEventPublisher` as suggested [in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/session-management.html#ns-concurrent-sessions). As for your other questions, please open a new stackoverflow question. Comments on SO are not intended to be used for Q&A discussions.